# We choose $2$ cards from $15$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The integers $1,2,3,4,...,13,14,15$ are written on cards. Two cards are taken out at random. Find the probability that the sum of the numbers on the chosen cards is equal to $10$.

We can choose $2$ from $15$ cards in $C_{15}^2=\dfrac{15\times14}{1\times2}$ different ways. Now $$10=1+9\\10=2+8\\10=3+7\\10=4+6$$ so $$P(A)=\dfrac{m}{n}=\dfrac{4}{C_{15}^2}.$$ I am not sure if we should multiply $4$ by $2$ to get the valid outcomes. I mean are $1;9$ and $9;1$ different outcomes? What happens if we have e.g. the numbers $1,2,3,4,...,9999$ and we want to find the probability that the sum of the numbers on the chosen cards is equal to $2021$? We can't write all numbers and see which sum to $2021$... Is there a more general approach to problems of that sort?

Comment: No you don't care about permutations, because this is a combination type problem if it makes sense? Your answer is correct. For $2021$, the answer is $\frac{n+1}{2}-2$ not counting permutations, and $(0,n)$ and $(n,0)$ as a solution. So the answer is $\frac{1009}{2041210}$, where the denominator is $2021$ choose $2$.

Comment: I recommend using the far more common notation $\binom{15}{2}$ rather than this $C$ notation you use.  Of course, use the notation your teacher uses while in their class... but to avoid confusion since $C^n_k$ is also used (*and is more common*) rather than $C_n^k$ to denote the number of subsets of size $k$ from an $n$-element set, it is better to avoid that notation entirely.

Comment: As for whether we should care about order, we can if we want to and it would give the same answer as though we didn't.  So long as we are *consistent* with our choice and our counting in the numerator made the same choice as to whether we care about order as our counting in the denominator.  That is to say, $\dfrac{4}{\binom{15}{2}}=\dfrac{8}{15\cdot 14}$

Answer (score 1):

I will consider the more general case having cards from **$1 ,... ,n$**.

Let **$m$** the outcome we are looking for.

The number of solutions for $m=x+y$ the number of such solutions is $m-1$ (you can see this as how to place a bar in $1111...11=m$ you have $m-1$ places )

Here we have two cases to consider :

1. $m$ is odd
   Hence $(m/2,m/2)$ is not a solution, in this case the probability is :
   $$\frac{m-1}{2{ n \choose 2}}$$
2. $m$ is even
   Hence $(m/2,m/2)$ is a solution but is not a faisable outcome, in this case the probability is :
   $$\frac{m-2}{2{ n \choose 2}}$$

Comment: You can further generalize the problem considering $k$ numbers to be taken